# creating a layout with Dreamweaver using Draw AP DIV Tool

Tags: css

I am new using Dreamweaver, in the design view i saw a option in the layout called Draw API DIV . By using this i got the css like this

```
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:895px;
    top:554px;
    width:279px;
    height:385px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: #C3D4EE;
}
```

Is this the right way of doing the layout for the website

Answer (score 0):

It's *a* way, but a very fragile one.

It is likely to cause text to overflow from containers when the font size changes (browsers tend to use page zooming rather then text resizing these days, but if the specified font isn't available on the client, then the substitute is likely to take up a different amount of space).

It will not flow to adapt to different viewport sizes (typically determined by window size on desktops/laptops and screen size on phones and tablets).

As a rule of thumb, any kind of layout produced by pointing and clicking is unsuitable for use on the WWW.

Comment: is there any other tool like that to draw the layout perfectly without any fragile

Comment: is the coding in html is the only way to make the layout  perfect